# How to listen to gtm events fire from javascript file in my webpage?

Tags: google-analytics, javascript, google-tag-manager

I am using gtm with Universal analytics tag in my website. I know gtm fires - "gtm.js", "gtm.click", "gtm.dom", "gtm.load" etc events and send event data to google analytics based on rules specified in the triggers. I want to listen to all these gtm events. And whenever any of these gtm events fires, I want to fetch the eventdata that it sends to google analytics, from my javascript attached in the webpage.

Can anyone tell me how can I trigger a my custom event in javascript whenever any of the gtm events trigger and fetch that event data it sends to google analytics?
Simply, What code should I write in js to listen gtm.click like event and fetch the data that it sends to google analytics?

Comment: What are you hoping to do with this data? Temporary setup testing/troubleshooting, or something more? If it's just "look at it sometimes" the GTM Preview mode might do everything you need.

Answer (score 1):

These things you mention are listeners. I’m wondering the same as Reve, what do you try to accomplish? Most triggers for pageviews or events depend on these triggers. Here is a list how they do:

- gtm.js is equal to the “pageview” trigger. Meaning GTM script is
  loaded and ready
- gtm.dom is when the DOM is loaded
- gtm.load is when the window is loaded
- gtm.click is to track clicks on the HTML markup
- gtm.linkClick is to track clicks on a-elements

So these do not actually send anything, they are the triggers that make sure you can send something.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest Logstalgia and gource. These softwares are free and are web server access log visualization tools. With these tools you will be able to see real-time and pre-recorded.